# select comparison operator on basis of parameter

Tags: sql

I want to compare columns on the basis of parameter

e.g.

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetTenderBySearch]
  (
      p_strOperator char(1),
    p_dtClosingDate datetime
  )
  AS

  Select * From MyTable
  Where Case p_strOperator
        When '=' Then MyColumn = p_dtClosingDate
        When '>' Then MyColumn > p_dtClosingDate
        When '<' Then MyColumn < p_dtClosingDate
  End
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Besides seeing only 1 column and 1 parameter, what does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE (p_strOperator = '=' AND MyColumn = p_dtClosingDate)
    OR (p_strOperator = '>' AND MyColumn > p_dtClosingDate)
    OR (p_strOperator = '<' AND MyColumn < p_dtClosingDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding non-SARGable OR, although I'm note sure this is much better...

```
 Where
    Case When p_strOperator = '=' THEN MyColumn ELSE p_dtClosingDate END = p_dtClosingDate
    AND
    Case When p_strOperator = '>' THEN MyColumn ELSE p_dtClosingDate+1 END > p_dtClosingDate
    AND
    Case When p_strOperator = '<' THEN MyColumn ELSE p_dtClosingDate-1 END < p_dtClosingDate
```